# Combining query and filter on same field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have address doc type which has city as field. The city field uses analyser

```
"keyword_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "keyword", # So that we don't split multi word city name
  "filter": ["lowercase"] # The search needs to case insensitive
}
```

How can I get any address which matches the give city 'X' or city is null. In sql it would be written as

```
SELECT * FROM address
WHERE city = 'X' or city IS NULL
```

I guess I have to use match query to get `city ='X'` and 'missing' filter to get `city IS NULL`. How can I combine this?

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch allows to combine queries with the bool query. Bool query has three fields:

- **must** (AND)
- **should** (OR)
- **must_not** (AND NOT)

The following elasticsearch query is a boolean query containing a should field, with two sub-queries:

- the first selects items with city field containing at least one token == "myCity"
- the second selects items without city field

Results of this query will be equivalent to `city = 'mycity' OR city IS NULL`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "mycity"
          }
        },
        {
          "filtered": {
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "city"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Some useful resources:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html